# align bootstrap form group elements to 50% right using css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

We need to make some of the form elements on right side with width 50%. We are getting complete bootstrap 3 form via some api request so we can't change the structure of the form. It is standard bootstrap 3 form. In the below example, we want to move only last field to right side with width 50%
of total form width.

```
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
// this needs to move right with width 50% including the label 
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fieldtoBeright">Right Field</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fieldtoBeright" placeholder="Right field">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

We have tried applying css but either all elements are moving on the right side or label is not moving but field is correctly moved. Please help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div>
    <form class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-6">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label for="fieldtoBeright">Right Field</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fieldtoBeright" placeholder="Right field">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Simply Add class {col-sm-offset-6}. Shifts 50% only in tabs and desktop for mobile also then add class {col-xs-offset-6}.